# S3::Error::SignatureDoesNotMatch: when I try and save a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

this is coming up on my save, not when I try and sign in. Here is my code:

```
service = S3::Service.new(
    :access_key_id     => S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    :secret_access_key => S3_SECRET
  )
puts "connection established with s3"

puts "finding bucket"
bucket = service.buckets.find("")
puts "building object"
object = bucket.objects.build("#{RAILS_ROOT}/jsonexport/ema.txt")
puts "saving object"
object.content = open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/export/ema.txt")
object.save
```

I can run all this code in the console until I get to object.save then it kicks this error:

```
S3::Error::SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/s3-0.3.0/lib/s3/connection.rb:209:in `handle_response'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/s3-0.3.0/lib/s3/connection.rb:196:in `send_request'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/s3-0.3.0/lib/s3/connection.rb:72:in `request'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/s3-0.3.0/lib/s3/service.rb:64:in `service_request'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/s3-0.3.0/lib/s3/bucket.rb:146:in `bucket_request'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/s3-0.3.0/lib/s3/object.rb:196:in `object_request'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/s3-0.3.0/lib/s3/object.rb:179:in `put_object'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/s3-0.3.0/lib/s3/object.rb:74:in `save'
from (irb):8
```

Does anyone have any advice or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... This worked.

```
    service = S3::Service.new(
    :access_key_id     => S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    :secret_access_key => S3_SECRET
  )
puts "connection established with s3"

puts "finding bucket"
bucket = service.buckets.find("euro")

puts "building ema"
object = bucket.objects.build("jsonexport/ema.json")
puts "saving ema"
object.content = open("jsonexport/ema.json")
object.save
```